# Открыть файл с расширением ".msg", через Intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent, outlook

В android приложение подгружаются файлы с различными расширениями, это картинки, документы MS Office (Word, Excel), PDF и т.д.
Все они открываются прекрасно этой функцией:

```
private fun sendIntentForFileInAssets(fileName: String) {
    val file = fileFromAsset(fileName)
    val uri = getUri(file)
    val mimeType = contentResolver.getType(uri) ?: "*/*"

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        setDataAndType(uri, mimeType)
    }

    try {
        startActivity(intent)
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Не удалось найти приложение для открытия файла с расширением [.${file.extension}]" +
                    "\n MimeType = [$mimeType]",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    }
}
```

Исключение только файл с расширением ".msg", т.е. письмо из Outlook.
Для него ContentResolver возвращает тип: "application/octet-stream", хотя судя по старым ответам на StackOverflow MimeType должен быть "application/vnd.ms-outlook".
Но "application/vnd.ms-outlook" пропал из [полного списка MimeType](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)
Как открыть файл ".msg" из android приложения?

Comment: А просто из проводника этот файл в телефоне открывается? Должно быть же установлено приложение для открытия таких файлов.

Comment: Нет, не открывается. Установлена мобильная версия Outlook на телефон. При выборе через файловый менеджер, вручную указываю Outlook, тот открывается и показывает Toast с текстом "Ошибка".  Не понимаю как открыть файл с расширением ".msg", если сама же мобильная версия Outlook  не открывает файл-письмо из десктопной версии.

Comment: Плюс смущает, что полно ответов на StackOverflow, что надо просто указать mimeType = "application/vnd.ms-outlook", чтобы стартанул Outlook, но он игнорирует этот MimeType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, [DrMcSheen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/280456/drmcsheen)!
Я пытался открыть файл-письмо именно через мобильную версию Outlook.
Но если даже загуглить, чем открыть msg на Android вываливает кучу приложений, но среди них нет Outlook, что забавно.
К примеру, [Open Letter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.letteropener) справляется с этой задачей хорошо.
После установки этого приложения функция начинает работать как надо, предлагая открыть файл в приложении.